# Swing draws 3 JLabels instead of one

Tags: java, swing

I don't really understand why this program draws three pawns instead of one and two of which seem to have a random(probably not so random) positions. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe1CD.png)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    static final int SCREEN_EDGE = 800;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = 64;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 100;
    final int[] x = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int[] y = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    boolean running = false;

    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_EDGE, SCREEN_EDGE));
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
        int[] position = {0,0};
        int[] position1 = {1, 0};
        new Pawn(position,-1);
    }

    private void startGame() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        int counter = 1;

        for (int y = 0; y < SCREEN_EDGE/UNIT_SIZE; y++) {

            // 1 == "white"   2 == "black"
            int color = (y % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;

            for (int x = 0; x < SCREEN_EDGE/UNIT_SIZE; x++) {
                g.setColor(color == 1 ? new Color(239,217, 181) : new Color(180, 136,98));
                g.fillRect(x*UNIT_SIZE, y*UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                color = color == 1 ? 2 : 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Figure.figures.length; i++) {

            JLabel figureSprite = new JLabel(Figure.figures[i].image, JLabel.CENTER);
            figureSprite.setSize(90,90);
            figureSprite.setLocation(Figure.figures[i].position[0] + 5,Figure.figures[i].position[1] + 5);
            this.add(figureSprite);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    }
}







import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class Figure{
    protected int value;
    protected ImageIcon image;

    protected int[][] possibleMoves;
    public int[] position;

    // white = -1    black = 1
    protected int whiteOrBlack;
    protected static int figureCount = 1;

    // int[figureCount][0 = x][1 = y][2 = color]
    public static Figure[] figures = new Figure[figureCount];


    public Figure(int value, int[] position, int[][] possibleMoves , int whiteOrBlack) {
        this.value = value;
        this.position = position;
        this.possibleMoves = possibleMoves;
        this.whiteOrBlack = whiteOrBlack;
        Figure[] oldFigures = figures;
        figures = new Figure[figureCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldFigures.length; i++) {
            figures[i] = oldFigures[i];
        }
        figures[figureCount - 1] = this;

        figureCount++;
    }

    public abstract void move(int[] coordinates);
}







import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Pawn extends Figure{


    public Pawn(int[] position, int whiteOrBlack) {
        super(1, position, new int[3][2], whiteOrBlack);
        super.image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("graphics/" + (whiteOrBlack == -1 ? "whitePawn.png" : "blackPawn.png")));
        Image newImage = super.image.getImage().getScaledInstance(90,90, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);
        super.image = new ImageIcon(newImage);

    }

    public void checkMoves(){
        for (int i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {

            if((position[0] - 1) == figures[i].position[0] && (position[1] + this.whiteOrBlack) == figures[i].position[1] && figures[i].whiteOrBlack != this.whiteOrBlack) {
                possibleMoves[0][0] = position[0] - 1;
                possibleMoves[0][1] = position[1] + this.whiteOrBlack;
            }else possibleMoves[0] = new int[2];
            if((position[0]) != figures[i].position[0] && (position[1]) != figures[i].position[1]){
                possibleMoves[1][0] = position[0];
                possibleMoves[1][1] = position[1] + 1;
            }else possibleMoves[1] = new int[2];
            if((position[0] + 1) == figures[i].position[0] && (position[1] + this.whiteOrBlack) == figures[i].position[1] && figures[i].whiteOrBlack != this.whiteOrBlack) {
                possibleMoves[2][0] = position[0] + 1;
                possibleMoves[2][1] = position[1] + this.whiteOrBlack;
            }else possibleMoves[2] = new int[2];

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void move(int[] coordinates) {

    }
}






import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    public GameFrame(){
        this.add(new GamePanel());
        this.setTitle("Chess");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}



public class ChessGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

I tried few thing like changing JLabel to BufferedImage but it would've generate other problems down the line like not being able to use MouseListener so i feel stuck. I would love to know why this code generates 3 textures too.

Comment: Don't modify the state of your component from within a `paint` method - `paint` should paint the current state, it should never modify it - this could cause a never ending loop of paint passes which could starve your system of resources

Comment: *"BufferedImage but it would've generate other problems down the line like not being able to use MouseListener"* - In this case, you'd need to know where the images are on the component, then you could use a `MouseListener` to check if the `MouseEvent` occurred within the bounding area of the image - this is basic collision detection workflows - not difficult

Comment: I think you should also have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to get a better understanding of how painting works and how you should use it.  If you need to update the UI on a regular bases you should also have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding FigureSprites from within the drawComponent() method. The more often you draw the window, the more figures you have to draw.

Instead within drawComponent() just draw the current state but do not modify it. Adding figures has to come from somewhere else. For example, you could create the necessary pawns in the constructor. Or in extra methods that might get triggered based on user input.

In case you modify the GamePanel's state enough so that it should get painted freshly, just invoke repaint(). Swing will mark this component for repainting and decide on it's own when to run the paint() method, which in turn will run paintComponent().